# PHP While Dynamic Page Title

Tags: php

I want to create a dynamic title for a page, I have the basics however, I got a PHP block and I need some help

this is my header.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
<!-- some extra code-->
```

and I want to change the title if `$food` is true to "Foods" and if false change to "another title"

```
<?php
$food = TRUE;
$title = 'initial title';
$counter = 1;


if($food == TRUE){
$title = 'Foods';
}else{
$title = 'another title';
}
?>
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: The code you posted looks good. It can be simplified to [`$title = $food ? 'Foods' : 'another title';`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file that contains the HTML after the code that sets `$title` and you're good to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main file should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php require_once("getTitle.php");?></title>
<!-- some extra code-->
```

And an additional file named **getTitle.php** should look like this:

```
<?php
$food = TRUE;
$title = 'initial title';
$counter = 1;


if($food == TRUE){
$title = 'Foods';
}else{
$title = 'another title';
}
echo($title)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses server side code. That means you cannot create dynamic content after the page loads. 
AKA if you want to change the title after the page has loaded and then the user changed the food value; You can't. You have to reload the page or use a POST.

To do the first, you can either use JavaScript to change the current page, or reload the page and use content found in a database by using PHP to talk to the database via SQL.
Look up form posts to do the latter.

Else, you can use PHP when the page loads, simply include the PHP code before the  and reference a value in your database. Also, do not use capitalised letters for true or false, these should always be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Okey so i will give a quiet simple answer but effective.

So we will say that you got two tiles, you current page file and your header.php file and it would look something like this.

**header.php**

```
if($food == true) {
    echo 'Food';
} else {
    echo 'something else';
}
```

**Page file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php $food = true; ?>
<title> <?php require_once('header.php'); ?> </title>
```

As you are setting the $food variable before the require you can reach it inside the header.php and there for setting your correct title.

Answer (score -1):

```
if($food = TRUE {
```

Two errors:

- For comparison (does this equal that): double = not single! : == not =
- Ending paren missing for "if" statement! : ($food) not ($food

By the way: Welcome to PHP! You'll get used to it. You will find many sites where you can copy/paste existing samples (like if statements) and then change what you want. Always go with "steal the code" before making it up yourself If It Works. Don't go round reinventing wheels. And try a couple tutorial sites that will let you walk through the learning process in an orderly fashion.

It does get easier, and it doesn't take long to get there. A couple hours of tutorial goes A Loooong Way. ;)

[edit: That's a bit rude. OP altered his post to include the fixes I provided, but didn't mark my answer as the solution. Now his code works and I'm being downvoted for posting the right answer (since it no longer applies due to the edit)? And it's obvious, but some still insist on downvoting. Wow. Just ... wow.]

Comment: sorry I dont know how i did not include those while writing this post